# How to send an auto trigger email to the end user when click on submit button from a common email id on sharepoint 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-email, send-email

I am stuck due to a problem, I have created a SOP Page for the various end users.

After reading the SOP users need to click on a submit button to acknowledge, post that 
users should get an auto email in their outlook from a fixed email id. I am trying using a shared mailbox and it works but now the problem is every users can't have the access to that mailbox so how will they receive the auto email when they clicked on the Submit button?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, it may be better to add a button to trigger a flow which will send an email to the current user. You may need to add a custom list web part to use it.

Here is an exmaple:https://wonderlaura.com/2018/07/18/button-in-sharepoint-list-to-trigger-microsoft-flow/

Comment: Thanks for prompt response, but I already have a sharepoint wiki page, and there is a button

Comment: @Sameer Here is an example to do so, have a check:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52544.sharepoint-online-trigger-a-microsoft-flow-with-button-click.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help Jerry